# Matplotlib fill blank image line by line, when I receive data from socket

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data coming from a socket.
I want in the beginning to create an empty image, then update this image every time I receive the data from the socket.
The problem is when I receive a huge amount of data (1024) and I want to display it, it takes time and hangs. Is it possible to speed it up little bit? 
I think the way I do it is the problem, so if anyone knows a better way please advise.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    for i in range(0,99): 
        self.image_array[i] = np.zeros(shape=(y,x))  # y lines, x = points

    #values are the received array 
    self.image_array[ch_id][line] = self.values  from socket

    ax1.imshow(self.image_array[ch_id],cmap='gray',interpolation='nearest',
            origin='lower')

    plt.draw()
    plt.clf()
```

When I receive the data is it possible that instead of replacing the data, it is appending or something?
Is there is better way to initialize the array instead of `np.zeros(...`

Comment: you should remove the `plt.clf`, that is clearing your figure before you can see it

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to create a new image every time new data arrives from the socket. You can create a single image on initialisation, then update the values in the array from the data you are receiving:

```
  # on initialisation
  self.im = imshow(np.zeros((x,y)),cmap='gray',interpolation='nearest',
        origin='lower')
  ...

  # on update
  self.im.set_data(self.values)
  self.im.set_clim(self.values.min(),self.values.max())
  self.im.figure.canvas.draw()
```